# PHP Session variable not getting set

Tags: php, session

In one page of our site, I have this code:

```
$_SESSION['returnURL'] = "/store/checkout/onepage";
```

and further down, this button control:

```
<button type="button" title="Register Today" class="button" onclick="window.location = '/register/';" id="BecomeMember"><span><span>Become a Member Today</span></span></button>
```

Now, in the register template, I have this code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="returnURL" id="returnURL" value="<?php if(isset($_SESSION['returnURL'])) { echo $_SESSION['returnURL']; } else { echo '/'; } ?>" />
```

But it only shows the value as /.

What could be going on that is causing this?

Comment: session_start() is called elsewhere.

Comment: I printed out the $_SESSION array in the register template and it was an empty array.

Comment: Is te register template being  included with the above page an or is the variable being properly passes? What is your code for the template

Comment: Various possibilities: The session is getting closed. The variable is being unset. The template is applied before session_start() is called. We would need to see more code to determine the real source of the problem.

Comment: The page where I'm setting the variable is a Magento onepage checkout screen. The register template is an ExpressionEngine template. Could it be that because of the disparity of these two frameworks that they have their own sessions? How can I setup one that will be used for both>?

Comment: WOW, I even modified it to use a $_COOKIE variable and it still didn't work. There seems to be some weird differences here that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Looks like cookie domains are setup differently between the 2 systems. THat can cause this behavior so I'll have to work on this a little more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was sending a post variable to the page. The difference in the sessions between ExpressionEngine and Magento makes this prohibitive using session variables as well as cookies.

Answer (score 13):

first.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['returnURL'] = "/store/checkout/onepage";
echo '<a href="second.php">Pass session to another page</a>';
?>
```

second.php

```
<?php
session_start();
echo 'returnURL = ' . $_SESSION['returnURL'];
?>
```

So you need to write `session_start()` in both your files

Comment: If I place session_start() in this file, I get Session has already been started warning.

Comment: You need to describe the structure of your scripts more detailed: which file session starts, how you move to another file and so on. The code I writed is just general approach.

Comment: See comments in original post.

Comment: Having `session_start();` at the start of BOTH of my files was my issue.  I had `session_start();` at the beginning of my login page, but not the next page!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To solve this problem, you will need to:

1) Ensure that `session_start()` is called at the beginning of the script, before anything else.

2) Nothing is unsetting `$_SESSION` or `$_SESSION['returnURL']`.

Comment: If I place session_start() in this file, I get Session has already been started warning.

Comment: Output buffering will fix that issue

Comment: No can do, see comments in original post.

Answer (score 2):

i was able to get this to work like this

```
session_start();
$returnurl = "/store/checkout/onepage";
$_SESSION['returnURL'] = $returnurl;
```

Comment: That is exactly what DaneSoul did.

Answer (score 0):

I just fund i had the same kind of issue, sessions working fine in firefox but not chrome, i created a test script that would just create a session and then print out the session_id() in order to see if it was getting created or not, after running this script i noticed that the session_id() would change on every page load and that php was throwing a warning about the date/time not being set. I then added

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');

to the start of the script this stoped a new session_id() from getting generated on every page load and fixed the problem. (it might be worth noting that my issue only seemed to show up on my sub domain and not the top level domain)

Answer (score 0):

the server I was working on was full and thus session didn't work as there was no space to store values. Make sure your server has space.

Answer (score 0):

The session_start() function must be the very first thing in your document. Before any HTML tags.

```
session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!--First Line like as-->
 <?php session_start();?>
 <!-- Now, your php or html codes-->
<html>
  <head>
   .....
   .....
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.

Comment: Is this an answer? This was already suggested a few years ago.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen many CMSes and frameworks having a different way of handling regular sessions. If the basic two-liner described above does not work (because it interferes with the current software), you can still use cookies for the same functionality. Remember, that cookies do not get deleted on closing the browser, so you need to tell it explicitly when to free up the variable (using unset).

```
$_COOKIE["something"] = 'value';
echo $_COOKIE["something"];
unset($_COOKIE["something"]);
```